# Arithmetic brownian motion. What is the solution when the time isn't 0?

Tags: differential-equations, brownian-motion, stochastic-processes

I very quickly need a formula for the value of $X$ when $X$ follows arithmetic brownian motion:

$$dX_s = \mu_s X_s ds + \sigma dW_s$$
I can find the formula online, but the difference is that we know $X_t = x$, for some $t> 0$, and we want a formula for $X_s$, $s > t$, in terms of $s-t$. The formula found online expresses $X_s$ in terms of $s$ only, since the start time is 0.